# Как получить всю матрицу без сокращений

Tags: python, numpy

Как получить всю матрицу без сокращений в виде строки? При использовании str() возвращается сокращённая матрица.

Comment: Добавьте минимальный пример

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[numpy.printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html) и `threshold` в [numpy.set_printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1001)
print(a)

with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf):
    print(a)
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> [   0    1    2 ...  998  999 1000]
> [   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
>    14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
>    28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41
>    42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54   55
>    56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69
>    70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83
>    84   85   86   87   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97
>    98   99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111
>   112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119  120  121  122  123  124  125
>   126  127  128  129  130  131  132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139
>   140  141  142  143  144  145  146  147  148  149  150  151  152  153
>   154  155  156  157  158  159  160  161  162  163  164  165  166  167
>   168  169  170  171  172  173  174  175  176  177  178  179  180  181
>   182  183  184  185  186  187  188  189  190  191  192  193  194  195
>   196  197  198  199  200  201  202  203  204  205  206  207  208  209
>   210  211  212  213  214  215  216  217  218  219  220  221  222  223
>   224  225  226  227  228  229  230  231  232  233  234  235  236  237
>   238  239  240  241  242  243  244  245  246  247  248  249  250  251
>   252  253  254  255  256  257  258  259  260  261  262  263  264  265
>   266  267  268  269  270  271  272  273  274  275  276  277  278  279
>   280  281  282  283  284  285  286  287  288  289  290  291  292  293
>   294  295  296  297  298  299  300  301  302  303  304  305  306  307
>   308  309  310  311  312  313  314  315  316  317  318  319  320  321
>   322  323  324  325  326  327  328  329  330  331  332  333  334  335
>   336  337  338  339  340  341  342  343  344  345  346  347  348  349
>   350  351  352  353  354  355  356  357  358  359  360  361  362  363
>   364  365  366  367  368  369  370  371  372  373  374  375  376  377
>   378  379  380  381  382  383  384  385  386  387  388  389  390  391
>   392  393  394  395  396  397  398  399  400  401  402  403  404  405
>   406  407  408  409  410  411  412  413  414  415  416  417  418  419
>   420  421  422  423  424  425  426  427  428  429  430  431  432  433
>   434  435  436  437  438  439  440  441  442  443  444  445  446  447
>   448  449  450  451  452  453  454  455  456  457  458  459  460  461
>   462  463  464  465  466  467  468  469  470  471  472  473  474  475
>   476  477  478  479  480  481  482  483  484  485  486  487  488  489
>   490  491  492  493  494  495  496  497  498  499  500  501  502  503
>   504  505  506  507  508  509  510  511  512  513  514  515  516  517
>   518  519  520  521  522  523  524  525  526  527  528  529  530  531
>   532  533  534  535  536  537  538  539  540  541  542  543  544  545
>   546  547  548  549  550  551  552  553  554  555  556  557  558  559
>   560  561  562  563  564  565  566  567  568  569  570  571  572  573
>   574  575  576  577  578  579  580  581  582  583  584  585  586  587
>   588  589  590  591  592  593  594  595  596  597  598  599  600  601
>   602  603  604  605  606  607  608  609  610  611  612  613  614  615
>   616  617  618  619  620  621  622  623  624  625  626  627  628  629
>   630  631  632  633  634  635  636  637  638  639  640  641  642  643
>   644  645  646  647  648  649  650  651  652  653  654  655  656  657
>   658  659  660  661  662  663  664  665  666  667  668  669  670  671
>   672  673  674  675  676  677  678  679  680  681  682  683  684  685
>   686  687  688  689  690  691  692  693  694  695  696  697  698  699
>   700  701  702  703  704  705  706  707  708  709  710  711  712  713
>   714  715  716  717  718  719  720  721  722  723  724  725  726  727
>   728  729  730  731  732  733  734  735  736  737  738  739  740  741
>   742  743  744  745  746  747  748  749  750  751  752  753  754  755
>   756  757  758  759  760  761  762  763  764  765  766  767  768  769
>   770  771  772  773  774  775  776  777  778  779  780  781  782  783
>   784  785  786  787  788  789  790  791  792  793  794  795  796  797
>   798  799  800  801  802  803  804  805  806  807  808  809  810  811
>   812  813  814  815  816  817  818  819  820  821  822  823  824  825
>   826  827  828  829  830  831  832  833  834  835  836  837  838  839
>   840  841  842  843  844  845  846  847  848  849  850  851  852  853
>   854  855  856  857  858  859  860  861  862  863  864  865  866  867
>   868  869  870  871  872  873  874  875  876  877  878  879  880  881
>   882  883  884  885  886  887  888  889  890  891  892  893  894  895
>   896  897  898  899  900  901  902  903  904  905  906  907  908  909
>   910  911  912  913  914  915  916  917  918  919  920  921  922  923
>   924  925  926  927  928  929  930  931  932  933  934  935  936  937
>   938  939  940  941  942  943  944  945  946  947  948  949  950  951
>   952  953  954  955  956  957  958  959  960  961  962  963  964  965
>   966  967  968  969  970  971  972  973  974  975  976  977  978  979
>   980  981  982  983  984  985  986  987  988  989  990  991  992  993
>   994  995  996  997  998  999 1000]
> ```